# Use of the plural form for "flotsam"

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm having a discussion on whether the word flotsam is used only in a singular context or if it can be used as a plural. Can you help me which sentence is grammatically correct? Instinctively the first sounds better to me, however I cannot explain why. Do they have a different meaning?

> Marine flotsam **includes** wood, algae and plastic.

or

> Marine flotsam **include** wood, algae and plastic.

Comment: _Flotsam_ is very definitely a mass noun, so it and the verb should be singular.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the Oxford Dictionary Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flotsam?q=flotsam), both *flotsam* and the related *jetsam* are [mass nouns](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mass-noun?q=mass%20noun)—they refer not to discrete items but to something that's not typically regarded as countable. Thus, both these words are always used with a singular verb; they have no plural forms.

Comment: It's the difference between "stuff" and "things". Flotsam is "stuff". The logs you may recover near shore are "things", but together they make "stuff".